# Programatically get available movements evil emacs

Tags: key-bindings, evil, commands, motion

Is there a way to programatically get the available movement commands for evil emacs?

Preferably also with the key they are currently bound to.

(There are a lot of commands for movement, but I do not know whether they are grouped or categorized in a way that makes them accessible as movement commands.)

Comment: What exactly is this for, an Evil cheatsheet?

Comment: Something similar, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this question weren't about programmatic access (for designing something like a printable cheatsheet), I'd suggest you to look at either `evil-maps.el` or `evil-motions` in `evil-vars.el`.

Evil's motions are bound in `evil-motion-state-map`, so a possible approach would be just traversing that keymap and tracking both the key and command while doing so.  The problem with that is that (surprise, surprise), it's not just motions there, for example `digit-argument` is bound there to the number keys.

An alternative approach would be traversing `evil-command-properties` (which is a variable altered by every Evil command defined) and looking for items with `:repeat motion` as their property, these should be motions.  You could then look up what key these are bound to.